# How kernel headers are involved in building gcc toolchain?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, glibc, newlib

I have learned that the kernel headers specify how programs can interact with the kernel, so they must be involved in building the standard library, or? I have just read a tutorial which explains quite good how to build an arm-elf toolchain (http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GNU_ARM-Toolchain).

What confuses me is, that no kernel headers are involved in this process. They configure gcc with

```
../gcc-4.3.2/configure --target=arm-elf --prefix=/opt/gnuarm --enable-interwork --enable-multilib --enable-languages="c,c++" --enable-target-optspace --with-float=soft --with-newlib --with-headers=../newlib-1.16.0/newlib/libc/include/ --disable-nls
```

and Newlib with

```
../newlib-1.16.0/configure --target=arm-elf --prefix=/opt/gnuarm --enable-interwork --enable-multilib --enable-target-optspace --with-float=soft
```

It seams to me that they only take headers from newlib (they use newlib instead of glibc). The files in this directory look quite generic. I expect that a Linux "kernel version" appears somewhere in this process but it doesn't. I thought that the Linux ABI can change from kernel version to kernel version. How is the "connection" between kernel (headers) and a gcc toolchain?

Answer (score 1):

The example you are building is for newlib, a bare metal libc implementation. That means there is no OS needed to run the binaries, no Linux headers needed to build.

If you build glibc or musl toolchains.  You would need Linux headers.

Answer (score 0):

The GNU C Library cannot be built without the Linux kernel headers. Most C library functions are implemented using system calls, and the kernel headers define the system call interface. The headers come with the kernel source, of course, but the source must be patched and configured for the processor architecture before they can be used to build the C library.